# How can I access the files (saved on my computer) that I created with Atom through Git Bash?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am very new to coding, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.
I uploaded Atom and created a file that is saved on my computer. But it isn't accessible through the command line (GitBash). I've tried:

`ls ~/AppData/Local/atom/bin` , `/c/path/to/atom`, `ls ~/AppData/Local/atom`

Comment: Well where is the file? Please [edit] to add details. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Git or Atom -- it seems like you just don't know where the file is, or you don't know how to access it in Git Bash.

Comment: Try `ls ~` or `ls ~/Documents`

Comment: You uploaded Atom?!